# Removing Elements From One List If not contained in another List. C#

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine

What is the best way for me to remove an element from `List<> A` that is not in `List<> B`. On Top of this before I remove the `Element` I need to run a function on that `Element` (Callback is run when value changed).

For Example

```
List<Chunk> ActiveChunks = //List Of Active Chunks.
void UpdateChunks()
{
   List<Chunk> chunks = //Chunks To Activate
   if (ActiveChunks[Element] is not Contained In chunks){
      A.Active = False
      A.Remove[Element]
   }
   //After Removing Chunks That do not exist in "chunks" add from chunks to ActiveChunks What is not In already in Chunks
}
```

What My Code Looks Like

```
private List<Chunk> ActiveChunks = new List<Chunk>();
private void OnPlayerMoved(Character c)
{
    //Current chunk That Player is in
    List<Chunk> chunks = new List<Chunk>();
    for (int i = -(GameManager.ViewRange - 1); i < GameManager.ViewRange - 1; i++)
    {
        Chunk chunk = world.ChunkAtWorldPos(c.PosX + i, c.PosY + i);
        if (chunk != null)
            chunks.Add(chunk);
    }
    if (ActiveChunks.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (Chunk chunk in ActiveChunks)
        {
            if (chunks.Contains(chunk) == false)
            {
                chunk.Active = false;
            }
        }
        //This Line From Answer down Below
        ActiveChunks.RemoveAll(x => x.Active == false);
        foreach (Chunk chunk in chunks)
        {
            if (ActiveChunks.Contains(chunk) == false)
            {
                chunk.Active = true;
                ActiveChunks.Add(chunk);
            }
        }
    }
    else
        ActiveChunks.AddRange(chunks);
}

public class Chunk
    {
        //Position
        public readonly int X;
        public readonly int Y;

        public Tile[,] Tiles;

        private bool active = false;
        public bool Active{
            get{return active;}
            set{
                if (value == true && value != active)
                    cbOnActivate?.Invoke(this);
                else if (value != active)
                    cbOnDeactivate?.Invoke(this);

                active = value;
            }
        }

        Action<Chunk> cbOnActivate;
        Action<Chunk> cbOnDeactivate;

        //Constructor
        public Chunk(int X, int Y)
        {
            this.X = X;
            this.Y = Y;
        }

        void RegisterOnActivateCallback(Action<Chunk> callback){
            cbOnActivate += callback;
        }
        void RegisterOnDeactivateCallback(Action<Chunk> callback){
            cbOnActivate += callback;
        }
    }
```

Comment: See LINQ / IEnumerable “Contains” or “Any” for a start.

Comment: You'll want Linq, but rather `Intersect` in the form of `ListA = ListA.Intersect(ListB)`  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/set-operations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way.

The following code will change `Active` to false for chunks in `activeChunks` that are not found in `chunks`.

I assumed:

- chunks in both lists have an `Id` property
- there are not chunks in `activeChunks` with `Active==false` that you want to keep.

```
var chunksInActiveChunksThatDontExistInChunks = 
    activechunks.Where( ch => !chunks.Any( ch => ch.Id == chunk.Id ));

// Since it seems you're not familiar with Linq
// please be aware that this will not be evaluated until foreach is executed
// You can evaluate it earlier by calling ToList() 
// e.g. var chunksIn... = activechunks.Where(...).ToList();


foreach( var chunk in chunksInActiveChunksThatDontExistInChunks )
{
    chunk.Active = false;
}

activeChunks.RemoveAll(x => x.Active == false);
```

You could use `Contains` if your object match, but I don't know if they do so I went with `.Id`. It could be:

```
var chunksInActiveChunksThatDontExistInChunks = 
    activechunks.Where( ch => !chunks.Contains(ch));
```

---

For

> //After Removing Chunks That do not exist in "chunks" add from chunks to ActiveChunks What is not In already in Chunks

you could:

```
var chunksThatAreInChunksButNotInActiveChunks = 
    chunks.Where( ch => !activeChunks.Any( ch => ch.Id == chunk.Id ));

activeChunks.AddRange(chunksThatAreInChunksButNotInActiveChunks);
```

---

*Please note that this **not** good if the lists are modified by others while this is being executed.*

Comment: What does "ch" stand For? + Chunk does not have an "Id"

Comment: In this context `ch` stands For the element in `activechunks` that is currently being processed in the Linq operation (`Where`).

Comment: `activechunks.Except(chunks)`

Comment: Could you please include the declaration for Chunk? If might be important to understand how to compare them, as @tymtam noted here, he had to assume how to compare two Chunks.

Comment: @CoryNelson yeah, I too was thinking of .Except() and also since it needs an IEqualityComparer, it might be possible to call a function inside Equals() of GetHashCode().

Comment: @tymtam Does this make it more efficient than what I have. I read that behind the scenes it's doing close to the same thing is that correct or did I misunderstand something?

Answer (score 0):

```
var missing = ActiveChunks.Where(i => !chunks.Contains(i));
missing.ToList().ForEach(i => Console.WriteLine(i));
var activeMinusMissing = ActiveChunks.Where(i => missing.Contains(i));
ActiveChunks = activeMinusMissing;
```

`missing` is a list which contains items that were in `ActiveChunks` but are missing from `chunks` (e.g. the ones you want removed)

the `Console.WriteLine()` can be any function you like and it is run on each item to be removed

`activeMinusMissing` is a list that contains the items from `ActiveChunks` minus the items to be removed (e.g. the ones in ActiveChunks but not in chunks).
Instead of removing the items from `ActiveChunks`, you can just replace `ActiveChunks` with `activeMinusMissing`.

The `activeMinusMissing` variable is just for demonstration so you can replace the last two lines with

```
ActiveChunks= ActiveChunks.Where(i => missing.Contains(i)).ToList();
```

So the final code would be

```
var missing = ActiveChunks.Where(i => !chunks.Contains(i));
missing.ToList().ForEach(i => Console.WriteLine(i));
ActiveChunks= ActiveChunks.Where(i => missing.Contains(i)).ToList();
```

Answer (score -1):

according to your code,i think, activechunks is finally the same chunks. No need to add and remove element. remove all activechunks element and add all chunks's element into activechunks.

Comment: What if `activeChunks` contains elements that `chunks` doesn't?

Comment: hm.. you are right. sorry.

Comment: And I need to be able to deactivate the chunk before I remove it.